# Symfony2: Create two controllers one to display a form and other to handle the submission

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hi I am a new to the Symfony2 MVC framework. What I have achieved so far is rendering a form in a twig template using the twig template. What I want to do next is create second (separate) controller to deal with form submission. Can you share with me how to achieve this.

I have read the symfony2 documentation however, it is not working.

Many thanks:)

Comment: why not handle submission in same controller and same action ? have a look at [Handling Form Submissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

Comment: I agree with @MKhalidJunaid. GET and POST action flows are usually more than 50% the same. Why not use that to your advantage?

Comment: How could I do this. Can you show me a simple example. I want my user to make a simple enquiry: The fields could be firstname, email and enquiry for example

Comment: That's a pretty typical use case and could be done only using 1 controller like the others have said. The [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) provide a through walk through.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an action on the form you are generating like so:

```
public function generateSearchBarAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        //This is where we are defining the target route
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('route_to_catch_the_request'))
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('keyword')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    return $this->render('search_bar.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

The controller that is provided at `route_to_catch_the_request` can then catch the request.

```
public function showSearchKeywordsAction(Request $request)
{
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
         //do whatever...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the CreateForm rather than the createFormBuilder hence can I use shall I define the action in the formAbstract class?

Comment: `createform()` requires a formtype as an argument. You can add `setAction()` to the formtype that you referenced.

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can also add the route directly in the twig template i.e inside the form tags as the post url parameter